# Posting a list of record in Swagger

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, swagger

I have an entity called experience that contains a list of Activities.
How do I set my controller and my swagger testing environment that helps me to add and experience and at the same time adding a list of record of activities with a foreign key already included ?

Comment: improve your question by adding what you have done till now and what issue you are facing.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have an entity called experience that contains a list of Activities.
> How do I set my controller and my swagger testing environment that
> helps me to add and experience and at the same time adding a list of
> record of activities with a foreign key already included ?

To transfer related entities in swagger, you can use the `[FromBody]` attribute, code like this:

```
public class Experience
{
    public int ExpId { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
}

public class Activity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

and the API controller method:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ToDoController : ControllerBase
{
    // POST api/<TodoController>

    [HttpPost("AddExperience")]
    public IActionResult AddExperience([FromBody]Experience experience)
    {
        return Ok(experience);
    }
```

After that in the swagger UI, send the parameters using json format.

[image]

The result as below:

[image]